# React Native Tab Navigation nested in Stack Navigation How To?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, navigation

I am new to react native, and have come across this issue with navigation. I have a 'main menu' (TabNav) that I want to render on every page.

I have some pages that are not accessible from the main menu (TabNav), but should still have the menu options. I'm not sure how to impliment this. Here is the code I have so far:

```js
const TabNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    Map: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: Details },
    });
    
const extraNav = createStackNavigator(
    {
        SinglePage: SinglePage,
        Tabs: TabNav
    }
);

const RootStackNav = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Tabs: {
            screen: TabNav
        },
        SinglePage: {
            screen: extraNav,
        }
    },
);
```

I navigate to the single separate page via:

```js
render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
            <View>
                <Icon 
                    name='place'
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SinglePage')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

What I want to happen is when I navigate to the single separate page my "main menu" is still present.
Right now I can navigate to all the pages, but on the single separate page the tabs are not available, and I have to hit 'back' to access it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to nest a stack navigator to a tab navigator

```
const RootTabNav = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
    Map: { screen: HomeScreen },
    DetailStack: { screen: stackNav},
});

const stackNav= createStackNavigator(
    {
        SinglePage: { screen: SinglePage}
        Details: { screen: Details },
    }
);
```

Its just an example of nesting stack to tabNavigator. I hope this may help you.

Comment: Is there a way to do that the other way? So put the tab nav into the stack?

Comment: yes you can put the tabNav to a stackNav but your main menu is not accessible in anywhere out of tabNav. for example you can make a rootStackNav containing splashScreen, LoginPage and a tabNav. but if you want to access main menu from all pages, you have to put all pages in tabNav. (you can make a stackNav with just one screen=tabNav)

Comment: Okay, so basically I would have to inflate my tabnavs to have one for EVERY page I want my main menu on.